# how to get $.ajax settings in response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to know if the original $.ajax() call was made with `dataType: 'text'`.

Is there anyway to see this in the `.done()` handler? I was trying `$.ajaxSettings()` but I do not see an option for `dataType`.

Comment: Use the `this` keyword, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24071068/952310).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not explicitly setting the `context` argument for the ajax settings, then the `this` pointer inside of `.done()` is the jqXHR object that was created when you started the ajax call (with promise methods added).  That object contains any custom settings you used such as `dataType`.  So, you can simply reference the `dataType` with:

```
this.dataType
```

in the `.done()` handler as in:

```
$.ajax('example.php', {dataType: "json"}).done(function(data) {
    var type = this.dataType;
});
```

---

If you are using the `context` property which will change `this`, then you can  save the `dataType` in a local variable before you make the ajax call and access it via that closure:

```
function yourFunc() {
    var type = "json";
    $.ajax('example.php', {dataType: type, context: someOtherObject}).done(function(data) {
        // can access the local variable type here
    });
}
```

Comment: Not strictly true about what `this` will be. From the jQuery docs: "The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context` option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves." - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: @MattTester - OK, my comment applies IF the OP is NOT using the `context` argument which there is no evidence they are.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yep, useful to know about `context` sometimes. Your answer get my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

What about doing the following:

```
.done(function(data){ console.log(this.dataType); });
```

`this`, in that context, represents the jqXHR object that was created when you started the ajax call.